# FireBase database only updated when there is a Debug.Log

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following function that I call from other scripts when I want to update the FireBase realtime database:

```
public async Task UpdateCoins(int coins)
{
    string playerID = await GetPlayerID();
    await usersRef.Child(playerID).Child("coins").SetValueAsync(coins);
}
```

When I call the function like this:

```
await UpdateCoins(coins)
```

or

```
_ = UpdateCoins(int coins)
```

The database is not updated, but if I add a `Debug.Log()` to the function, the database is updated correctly:

```
public async Task UpdateCoins(int coins)
{
    Debug.Log("Test");

    string playerID = await GetPlayerID();
    await usersRef.Child(playerID).Child("coins").SetValueAsync(coins);
}
```

Any ideas for the reason of this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

It might have something todo with running the Task on the main thread or not.  I recall from past experience that you should always run Firebase code on the main thread in Unity, by adding the Debug.Log() that's maybe happening behind the scenes and when omitted it gets run on a different thread.  The google Firebase team discuss it here.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5GzFDXvZxKM&t=83s.

Apologies I don't have a blank Unity firebase project to hand to check the following syntax but I think you can do the above without the 'await' and Tasks with a MonoBehaviour.  In the google documentation they don't use await.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/save-data
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/unity/manage-users

```
// can get the current user with 
Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser user;
Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth auth;

// Handle initialization of the necessary firebase modules:
void InitializeFirebase() {
  Debug.Log("Setting up Firebase Auth");
  auth = Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
 // then the user is a property with an id
 user = auth.CurrentUser;

// your code would then be
playerID = user.uid;
usersRef.Child(playerID).Child("coins").SetValueAsync(coins);
}
```